# Why is sam package uploading artifacts every time?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

when I run Sam package, it uploads my lambda function packages to s3 every time even if I run it repeatedly without changing anything. I have one pipeline where I can see that it says “skipping upload” because the same package already exists and that’s what I’m trying to replicate. Any ideas?

I ran sam package against a template with local CodeUri paths for several lambda functions. I ran it repeatedly.

I expect the second time it runs that is skips the artifact uploads because they were already uploaded the first time and the file system is identical.

Answer (score 0):

The SAM documentation states that:

> The SAM package command creates and uploads artifacts based on the
> package type of a given resource. It uploads   local images to ECR for
> `Image` package types. It creates zip of your code and dependencies
> and uploads it to S3 for   other package types. The command returns a
> copy of your template, replacing references to local artifacts with
> the   AWS location where the command uploaded the artifacts.

That being said, every time there you run the command, it will check for updates and upload the new artifact if needed.

Like this:

```bash
$ sam package -t template.yaml --resolve-s3

        Managed S3 bucket: aws-sam-cli-managed-default-samclisourcebucket-1p0mvml741ygf
        A different default S3 bucket can be set in samconfig.toml
        Or by specifying --s3-bucket explicitly.
Uploading to 81ef6ef4d5aa0055f271fcfaeb7fab09  65210 / 65210  (100.00%)
File with same data already exists at 81ef6ef4d5aa0055f271fcfaeb7fab09, skipping upload
File with same data already exists at 81ef6ef4d5aa0055f271fcfaeb7fab09, skipping upload
File with same data already exists at 81ef6ef4d5aa0055f271fcfaeb7fab09, skipping upload
File with same data already exists at 81ef6ef4d5aa0055f271fcfaeb7fab09, skipping upload
File with same data already exists at 81ef6ef4d5aa0055f271fcfaeb7fab09, skipping upload
File with same data already exists at 81ef6ef4d5aa0055f271fcfaeb7fab09, skipping upload
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
[...]
```

You don't really have to worry about this, if there wasn't any changes, the upload will be skipped. If changes were made, you'll be able to see them in the output template.

I've got the doc text running `sam package -h` on my terminal.